# Is there some initialization area in ASP.NET that only runs once?

Tags: asp.net

I've got a piece of code that I want to run one time when my website is first loaded.
It is basically a static initialization of another module.

Is there some event I can hook into that runs when the site is first served to a client?
It doesn't even need to be per session, just on first load to any client.

I'm using vs2010, .net 4.0, asp.net 4.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the **Application_Start** event.

See MSDN [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)

> Application_Start is Called when the first resource (such as a page) in an ASP.NET
>   application is requested. The
>   Application_Start method is called
>   only one time during the life cycle of
>   an application. You can use this
>   method to perform startup tasks such
>   as loading data into the cache and
>   initializing static values.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks. Will accept when SO allows me to.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute.aspx), available as of ASP.NET 4.0. See [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx) for an example.